# How to write something in binary and assign it to a variable?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, can I define an integer constant in binary format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867365/in-java-can-i-define-an-integer-constant-in-binary-format)

In python, you can do something like:

`a = 0b00000010` which would set a to 2.

Is it possible to do something like that in Java? I know I could just go through and assign my varibles by the number instead of binary, but I like the visual.

Thanks ~Aedon

Comment: You can do the same thing in java 7 `a = 0b00000010`

Comment: this is a dup question.  answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867365/in-java-can-i-define-an-integer-constant-in-binary-format

Comment: You could wait for Java7, that supports binary literals (for some inexplicable reason)

Comment: @skaffman:  It's inexplicable that Java would support binary literals?  Is there a more self-documenting way of showing int masks in code?

Comment: @Mark Peters - Yessir, thats what I am doing now.

Comment: @All - Thanks all. I didn't know that Java 7 supported binary literals. Good to know, but I am working with android, which as far as I know isn't getting Java 7 for a while. Looks like I'm stuck with just using straight numbers.

Comment: what's wrong with hex `0x02`?

Comment: @ratchet freak - Nothing is wrong with it. But I am doing bitmask flags and wanted to visualize how the flags were laid out. Preference is in question here not functionality.

Comment: @ratchet: Hex can be really hard to visualize sometimes.  I've worked with protocols that stuff a field into an int from bits 2 to 7 for example.  If the bits you care about aren't aligned with a nybble it gets really messy in hex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Java 7, you can do

```
int a = 0b00000010;
```

However if you're working with an older version, I'm afraid you're stuck with

```
int a = Integer.parseInt("00000010", 2);
```

Comment: or you can write in hex using `0x`

`int i = 0x10;`

which is equal to

`int i = 16;`