# Bitwise Operators java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

my code is

```
final int CONST_1 = 1010;
final int CONST_2 = 1011;

System.out.println("CONST_1 & CONST_2: " + Integer.toBinaryString(CONST_1 & CONST_2));
System.out.println("CONST_1 ^ CONST_2: " + Integer.toBinaryString(CONST_1 ^ CONST_2));
System.out.println("CONST_1 | CONST_2: " + Integer.toBinaryString(CONST_1 | CONST_2));
System.out.println("~CONST_1 : " + Integer.toBinaryString(~CONST_1));
```

Output is

```
CONST_1 & CONST_2: 1111110010
CONST_1 ^ CONST_2: 1
CONST_1 | CONST_2: 1111110011
~CONST_1 : 11111111111111111111110000001101
```

In my opinion it's wrong and it should be:

```
CONST_1 & CONST_2: 1010
CONST_1 ^ CONST_2: 1
CONST_1 | CONST_2: 1011
~CONST_1 : 101
```

Please explain me why I have such result. Thanks!

Comment: The values you initialized your constants with are DECIMAL, not binary!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this:

```
final int CONST_1 = 1010;
final int CONST_2 = 1011;
```

to this:

```
final int CONST_1 = 0b1010;
final int CONST_2 = 0b1011;
```

Don't forget that literals are decimal by default. You clearly wanted them to be binary.

---

Binary literals require Java 1.7. So if that's not available, you can go with this:

```
final int CONST_1 = Integer.parseInt("1010",2);
final int CONST_2 = Integer.parseInt("1011",2);
```

Comment: I can't change it to final int CONST_1 = 0b1010;

Comment: it says Binary literals can only be used with source level 1.7 or greater

Comment: See this question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867365/in-java-can-i-define-an-integer-constant-in-binary-format) the `0b` prefix requires Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

`CONST_1` is `1010` in decimal. The binary value of `CONST_1` is `1111110010`. Similarly `CONST_2` is `1111110011`.

Does the result make more sense now?

Answer (score 1):

I think you know what is meant by a literal. If not, please refer: [Java Literals](http://www.roseindia.net/java/language/java-literals.shtml) and [Literal](http://java.about.com/od/l/g/literal.htm).

Now, Integer and Floating-Point literals are decimal by default in Java. So, the value `1010` you typed above will be decimal `1010`. ie., *One thousand and ten*. If you want them to be binary (it is clear from the question), there are many possibilities.

- Use equivalent decimal value.

You may use the decimal equivalent of the binary value you want to represent. Here, for example, decimal equivalent of binary `1010` is `10`, and that of binary `1011` is `11`.

```
final int CONST_1 = 10;
final int CONST_2 = 11;
```

- Use wrapper classes parse method

Each wrapper class has a parse method, which takes the base of number system also as argument. So

```
final int CONST_1 = Integer.parseInt("1010", 2);
final int CONST_2 = Integer.parseInt("1011", 2);
```

- If you are using Java 7, use binary literals

Binary literals are not supported in older versions of Java. Java 7 introduces binary literals. See [features](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html).

```
final int CONST_1 = 0b1010;
final int CONST_2 = 0b1011;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse an integer composed of only 0 and 1 with the binary representation of the integer...

The integer 1010 is 1111110010 in binary, so the results are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your numbers aren't binary.  They are written in decimal.  You want to prepend a 0b to tell Java 7 this int is in binary.  If you aren't using Java 7 there is no binary literal syntax so you can do this Integer.parseInt("1010", 2) as a work around or use HEX literal notation:

```
final int CONST_1_BINARY = 0b1010;
final int CONST_1_DECIMAL = 1010;

if( CONST_1_BINARY == CONST_1_DECIMAL ) {
   System.out.println("They are the same!");
} else {
   System.out.println("They are NOT the same.");
}
```