# Is byte not signed two's complement?

Tags: java, primitive

Given that byte,short and int are signed, why do byte and short in Java not get the usual [signed two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) treatment ? For instance 0xff is illegal for byte.

This has been discussed before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867365/in-java-can-i-define-an-integer-constant-in-binary-format) but I couldn't find a reason for why this is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the actual memory used to store `-1` in signed byte, then you will see that it is `0xff`. However, in the language itself, rather than the binary representation, `0xff` is simply out of range for a byte. The binary representation of `-1` will indeed use two's complement but you are shielded from that implementation detail.

The language designers simply took the stance that trying to store 255 in a data type that can only hold -128 to 127 should be considered an error.

You ask in comments why Java allows:

```
int i = 0xffffffff;
```

The literal `0xffffffff` is an `int` literal and is interpreted using two's complement. The reason that you cannot do anything similar for a byte is that the language does not provide syntax for specifying that a literal is of type `byte`, or indeed `short`.

I don't know why the decision not to offer more literal types was made. I expect it was made for reasons of simplicity. One of the goals of the language was to avoid unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Thanks good to know the implementation is two's complement. Why then does the language allow 0xffff_ffff for int ?

Answer (score 4):

You can write

```
int i = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

but you can't write

```
byte b = 0xFF;
```

as the 0xFF is an `int` value not a `byte` so its equal to 255.  There is no way to define a byte or short literal, so you have to cast it.

BTW You can do

```
byte b = 0;
b += 0xFF;
b ^= 0xFF;
```

even

```
byte b = 30;
b *= 1.75; // b = 52.
```

Comment: Thanks. I recently became aware of the implicit cast in +=. In Java i agree 0xff is int. It is what it is. But generally 0xff is signed 8 bits so should be assignable to byte. Anyway i think the question is answered - byte is implemented as two's complement.

Comment: What missing is a lack of a byte literal type so 0xFF can only by 255. There is no way to write 0xFF which is byte without a cast. c.f. `0xFFL` is a `long`

Comment: You are correct. However you _can_ write it. I.E. byte b = (byte) 0xFF; Of course it fails as -1 though :-)

Comment: @EddieB Do you mean it fails as `byte b = 255;` as you can write `byte b= -1;`

Comment: @peter-lawrey Yes sir. Please note that I'm a java-phite {new word?} in training. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

it is legal, but you need to cast it to byte explicitly, i.e. (byte)0xff because it is out of range.

Answer (score 1):

You can literally set a byte, but surprisingly, you have to use more digits:

```
byte bad = 0xff; // doesn't work
byte b = 0xffffffff; // fine
```

The logic is, that 0xff is implicitly 0x000000ff, which exceeds the range of a byte. (255)

It's not the first idea you get, but it has some logic. The longer number is a smaller number (and smaller absolute value).

```
byte b = 0xffffffff; // -1 
byte c = 0xffffff81; // -127 
byte c = 0xffffff80; // -128
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible values for a `byte` range from -128 to 127.

It would be possible to let values outside the range be assigned to the variable, and silently throw away the overflow, but that would rather be confusing than conventient.

Then we would have:

```
byte b = 128;
if (b < 0) {
  // yes, the value magically changed from 128 to -128...
}
```

In most situations it's better to have the compiler tell you that the value is outside the range than to "fix" it like that.