# Not ignoring 0 on Java

Tags: java, int

I need help, I have an `int num = 0000;` but on `System.out.print(num);` it only shows like this: `0`.
I would like to know what can I do if I have `num = 0111;` or `num = 0011;` or `num = 0001` and I want to show the 0 before the number, so the final result can be `0001` and not `1`.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to use a `String` instead.

Comment: but how can I do that?

Comment: You can do research ...

Comment: `String num = "0000";`

Comment: `System.out.println(String.format("%04d", 1));`

Comment: Beware, a leading `0` will make your value an octal one . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218760/why-is-08-not-a-valid-integer-literal-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `printf` instead:

```
System.out.printf("%04d", num);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print an int formated like this 0000, you have to do this:

```
int num = 23;
System.out.print(String.format("%04d", num));
// result -> "0023"
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use String datatype instead of int. Because in Java int automatically removes extra leading zeros.

Example:
 String num="0000";

As you know in integers Leading zeros have no impact.
From you input I think you are storing binary integers. 
If you want to store binary input to Integer kindly take a look on this answer.

[Use Binary in Int variable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867365/in-java-can-i-define-an-integer-constant-in-binary-format)

Thanks