# Representing an Integer in bits : Error

Tags: java, integer, byte, type-conversion

I am trying to declare an integer in bytes.
What i mean is : i am trying to declare int a = 4 as  int a = 0100(i have shortened it here to 4 bits for simplicity. ) 
Following is the code which i have used and is giving me unexpected output.

```
public class class4A_d {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world,this is the main function ");
    int q1=  00000100;  //8 bits 
    int q2 = 00000000000000000000000000000100; //32 bits
    System.out.println("q1 and q2 are respectively "+ q1 + ":" + q2); //q1= 64,q2 =64 
                                       }
                       }
```

I know java stores integers as 32 bits number in 2,s complement in the back end with weight of each bit progressing in the following manner: 
2(^0),2(^1),2(^2).....etc.
But here it seems that the weights are in the following manner :
8(^0),8(^1),8(^2).....etc.
Can anyone  explain this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, can I define an integer constant in binary format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867365/in-java-can-i-define-an-integer-constant-in-binary-format)

Comment: @Marged ..I had previously seen the link that you have mentioned,it does not answer my question mate.

Comment: Your bit constant is just wrong

Answer (score 2):

When you declare an int, you have the possibility to do it decimal, octal, hexadecimal and binary.

Binary:
Binary int constants begin with 0b, e.g.

```
int binary = 0b00000100; //decimal: 4
```

Octal:
Octal int constants begin with 0, so be careful because it can happen, that you use them accidentally, e.g.

```
int octal = 0127; //decimal 87
```

Hexadecimal:
Hexadecimal int constants begin with 0x, e.g.

```
int hex = 0xFF; //decimal 255
```

Comment: darn was just posting this ;)